# Nested loops & Simple Template Engine

Tags: python, bottle, python-3.4

I've got a problem with nested loops when I use them in [STPL](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/stpl.html).

Here is a part of **template.tpl**

```
 % for item in result:
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Label">{{''.join(item)}}</label><br>
         <p>
             % for item1 in result1:
                 {{''.join(item1)}}
             % end
         </p><br>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q{{''.join(item)}}">
     </div><br><br>
 % end
```

The problem is that this part of code returns me **all** elements from tuple **result1**

```
% for item1 in result1:
    {{''.join(item1)}}
% end
```

**result** and **result1** are tuples with data from SQLite 3

I need something like that:

```
...
<label>First element from tuple result</label>
<p>First element from tuple result1</p>
...
<label>Second element from tuple result</label>
<p>Second element from tuple result1</label>
...
...
```

Any ideas?:)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to build a list of 2-tuples that zips together the corresponding items from `result` and `result1`:

```
>>> result = [1 ,2, 3]
>>> result1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> zip(result, result1)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

You should do that in your view though, not in the template. From the view you can then simply return a new list containing your 2-tuples, let's call it `items`. In the template, you then just need one loop, and unpack the 2-tuples into separate variables:

```
 % for label, description in items:
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Label">{{''.join(label)}}</label><br>
         <p>{{''.join(description)}}</p><br>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q{{''.join(label)}}">
     </div><br><br>
 % end
```